# What kind bottom feeder is this?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

[image]

It’s about 2 1/2 inches long and had a little tail on the end. Also has short feelers that almost look like a moles.

Comment: By the first look it seems to be a lamprey. But I would suggest to give some more context to the place you took the animal. (see the [species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) tag wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a kind of loach. You have to include the location in your query. 
i.e. a black khuli loach:
[image]
a weather loach:

http://badmanstropicalfish.com/profiles/profile103.html